# Background image appearance in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a div having class as "gradient_back" to which i have applied a background.
The div looks ok in chrome and mozilla.
But in ie8 it doesn't get expanded as needed.

Here is the class 'gradient_back':

```
.gradient_back{
   width:100%;
   float:left;        
   background:url(images/gradient.gif) repeat-x 0 0;      
   background-size:auto 100%;
 }
```

I am not understanding this weird behaviour in ie8. Please help me resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think so, you should change some html like this.

<style type="text/css">
.top-gradient{
    width:100%;
    float:left;        
    background:url(images/top-gradient.gif) repeat-x 0 top;  
}
.bottom-gradient{
    width:100%;
    float:left;        
    background:url(images/bottom-gradient.gif) repeat-x 0 bottom;  
}
</style>

<div class="top-gradient">
    <div class="bottom-gradient">Your page content will go here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But its not working. The background image slides down and now white space is left above.

Comment: Can you send me your site url?

Comment: You can make two separate image of gradient and change html as per above.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not understanding this weird behaviour in ie8.

The first version of Internet Explorer to [support `background-size`](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) was version 9.

> Please help me resolve the problem.

I'd use [CSS gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) and fallback to a solid colour in older browsers.

Alternatively, you could try positioning the background image at `100% 100%` and not scaling it.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not support the CSS `background-size` feature. Therefore your `background-size:auto 100%` will not have any effect; no scaling will occur, and the background will be displayed in IE8 without stretching to fill the box.

You have a few choices:

1. Resize your background graphic manually so that it's the correct size without needing CSS to scale it.
2. Use a polyfill for `background-size`, such as the one in [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).
3. Use [feature detection](http://modernizr.com/) (or browser detection if you insist) to detect whether the browser supports `background-size`, and provide an alternative imgage or even just a plain solid colour if it doesn't.
4. Use an alternative feature like CSS Gradients. This is also not supported in IE8, but again you could use a polyfill for this (again, CSS3Pie has this covered).